# Getting "InvalidSignatureException" when trying to run "aws ecr-get-login-password" command in Azure DevOps pipeline shell

Tags: azure, azure-devops, amazon-ecr

I want to build and deploy Docker images from Azure DevOps to AWS ECR.

I followed this tutorial  -  https://www.devguides.dev/how-to-build-and-deploy-docker-images-from-azure-devops-to-aws-ecr/

I keep getting the following error:
`An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.`

I have manually checked the and ran the "aws ecr-get-login-password" command locally using the same AWS access key and secret and it does return a temp password so I know that the permissions and keys are correct.

I verified that I set the variables correctly and that they are read by having them printed out for me to view in the Azure bash shell - they were correct.

Any suggestions?

Do I need to provide AWS log in info somewhere else in Azure?

Below is the pipeline build yaml :

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - build-and-push-azure-to-aws

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - group: dev
  - name: DOCKER_REPOSITORY
    value: $(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID).dkr.ecr.$(AWS_REGION).amazonaws.com/$(DOCKER_REPOSITORY_NAME)

steps:
- script: |
    aws ecr get-login-password --region $(AWS_REGION) | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID).dkr.ecr.$(AWS_REGION).amazonaws.com
  displayName: 'Login to AWS'
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build docker image
  inputs:
    repository: $(DOCKER_REPOSITORY)
    command: buildAndPush
    Dockerfile: Dockerfile
    tags: |
      latest
```

Here is the error I get :

```
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.164.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/043d91c2-1246-45f3-909b-6594561cfbf1.sh

An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

Comment: Please set variable system.debug to True to see whether there is useful log. And if your just run `- script: aws ecr get-login-password --region $(AWS_REGION)` in your pipeline, how's the result? In addition, you can specify credentials using a service endpoint (of type AWS), and use AWS CLI, AWS Shell Script tasks to execute command in AWS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to build and deploy Docker images from Azure DevOps to AWS ECR, you could create the **service connection** with AWS with a set of your valid AWS credentials. You can follow this doc [AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/getting-started.html) to get more details of setting up this service connection.

[image]

And then use `Amazon ECR Push` task to push a Docker image to an Amazon Elastic Container Registry on AWS.

[image]

You may check the blog below to get more details:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-asp-net-core-web-application-to-amazon-ecs-using-an-azure-devops-pipeline/

Comment: Either they have removed this or you have to do something special for it to appear. It sure doesn't exist for me at least.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can recheck the keys
2. Check the system date time and AWS instance date time.
   The later was wrong in my case, refer this link https://www.learnitguide.net/2018/04/aws-cli-authfailure-access-credentials.html